# Why both SqlConnection and SqlTransaction are present in SqlCommand constructor?

Tags: design-patterns, ado.net, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I wonder, what is the reason to have this [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/352y4sff.aspx) constructor overload:

```
public SqlCommand(
    string cmdText,
    SqlConnection connection,
    SqlTransaction transaction
)
```

?

When I need to create an internal method that does its bit using a transaction provided as an argument, I always find it sufficient to only pass an `SqlTransaction` to that method, because, obviously, the connection will be `tran.Connection`.
Doesn't the same apply to this overload? Would it not be enough to only pass `cmdText` and `transaction`?

Is it actually possible to execute an `SqlCommand` against a connection, providing an `SqlTransaction` opened against a *different* `SqlConnection`? What will this result in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting observation because you cannot use a Transaction from a different Connection.  The System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand (4.0) has a private member called *ValidateCommand* that contains several validation checks, including this one:

```
if ((this._transaction != null) && (this._activeConnection != this._transaction.Connection))
{
    throw ADP.TransactionConnectionMismatch();
}
```

The overall design of the SqlCommand class is for flexibility.  The CommandText, Connection and Transaction properties (which are also exposed in the three additional constructor overloads) are read/write.  This makes the class flexible, but also prone to incorrect usage.

Certainly, things would be much cleaner if the properties were read-only and the constructors used as the primary means of passing data into the object.  In which case the following constructor would make much more sense:

```
public SqlCommand(string commandText, SqlTransaction transaction)
```

However, I would imagine that these properties are read/write to enable drag-n-drop designer support where the object is constructed using the default constructor and properties are set in the *InitializeComponent* method.